# How do I pass data from a background thread to the currently displayed activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, gps, locationlistener

I have two activities, A and B.  Activity A implements a LocationListener that periodically prints out the raw GPS coordinates the screen. Activity B is simply a MapActivity with a MapView.  I want to be able to pass the periodically-generated coordinates from A to B, even with A paused in the background and B in the foreground.  Turns out that the LocationListener indeed continues to retrieve the coordinates when activity A is paused.  With B in focus, then, how do I pass those values over from A?  Is startActivity(intent) appropriate for an activity that's already started and in the foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to constantly poll for location updates, consider making a "Sticky" service (but not like androidika). Check out the Remote Messenger [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) example. This will allow the activity to "hear" updates on the location from the service.

In my app, i made a base class that "heard" updates of location and if connectivity was lost. Then, the ui activities inherited from this base class. Thus, i could make two different activities receive updates, but minimize duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

I d' recommend using a service, that runs in the background. 
Or rather than having one activity decide when to update the location, write an IntentService that you launch from either of the 2 activities whenever you need them.
Take a look at [PlacesUpdateService](http://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/source/browse/trunk/src/com/radioactiveyak/location_best_practices/services/PlacesUpdateService.java) This does more than just look for the gps coordiantes, but it will give you the idea.

Comment: Whats the more appropriate API to use for the service to communicate with the foregrounded activity?